# dataframe groupby one column and average one column while finding most occuring in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to groupby one column while averaging one column and finding the most occuring value in another column

I was able to do it but I think there is a concise way to do it instead of 4 lines of code

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['USA', 'USA', 'Russia','USA', 'Russia', 'Russia'], 'City' : ['New-York', 'New-York', 'Sankt-Petersburg', 'Chicago', 'Moscow', 'Moscow'], 'Flights' : [22, 45, 32, 16, 31, 25]})
w=df.groupby('Country').mean().round(decimals=2)
x=(df.groupby('Country')['City'].agg(pd.Series.mode))
y=x.to_frame()
z = pd.concat([w, y], axis=1 ,join='outer')
```

```
Country   Flights   City

Russia    29.33         Moscow

USA       27.67         New-York
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with lambda functions, also for mode is possible add [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) for select first value,because [`mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) should return more values:

```
z = df.groupby('Country').agg({'Flights': lambda x: round(x.mean(), 2), 
                               'City': lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]})
print (z)
         Flights      City
Country                   
Russia     29.33    Moscow
USA        27.67  New-York
```

---

```
z = df.groupby('Country', as_index=False).agg({'Flights': lambda x: round(x.mean(),2), 
                                               'City': lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]})
print (z)

  Country  Flights      City
0  Russia    29.33    Moscow
1     USA    27.67  New-York
```